# Convert Unicode to Double Byte

Tags: c#, unicode

I have sqlserver table with one column of type `Image`  I'm using this code to recover it from my db.

```
public static byte[] ObtenerArchivo(string IdArchivo,bool GuardarEnDisco)
{
    byte[] archivo = null;
    MyContext db = new MyContext();
    Double Versiond = 1010;

    archivo = db.Versiones.Where(x => x.IntIdArchivo == IdArchivo && x.IntIdVersion == Versiond).Select(x => x.BinFisico).First();
    return archivo;
}
```

now to make mi file readable i need to convert it. This application was inherited from Visual FoxPro and after retrieve the file from my db must convert it with this function

```
**VFP Sintax 
STRCONV(lcImage, 6)

In VFP help it says: 

Converts character expressions between single-byte, double-byte, UNICODE, and locale-specific representations.
```

And **6** means:

```
6   Converts UNICODE (wide characters) to double-byte characters.
```

Now my Question is How can i do to make the same conversión in c#?

**EDIT 1:** If I can't as @Hans Passant  say's. and knowing I have stored text files, images, base 64 encoded files on that SQL Image field. How can  I do to store, retrieve and update those files to manage it with C#?

Comment: You can't, a *string* is not a suitable type to store binary data.  Such data will get corrupted when the string is normalized.  And your program can randomly crash when it contains a single surrogate character.  VFP dates from far simpler times.

Comment: @HansPassant Tks for your help. But now How can I do to proccess those files in c# ? What I did: I read it using StreamReader, then build my own string getting only pair bytes. It means get 0,2,4,6,8..... this way I get my original string but really this sounds to ugly for me and has a bad performance .. do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HansPassant Is ok about his apreciation but taking some special conditions in my case is posible to transform the string from doublé byte to single byte.

1- VFP translate text file to double byte it means my original file is **only text** single byte formated.

2- To decode my file just remove bytes added by vfp.

And here is the code:

```
public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string IdArchivo)
{
    string FinalData = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string NData = string.Empty;
            Byte[] BData = GetBinaryData(IdArchivo);
            string SData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(BData);
            for (int i = 0; i < SData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                    i++;

                if (i <= SData.Length - 1)
                    NData += SData[i];
            }
            return NData;
        });
    return FinalData;
}

public Byte[] GetBinaryData()
{

    // Just retrieve the file from my database 
}
```

This proccess remove all odd Bytes in the array and returns my string as I expected. Yes it is not so fast but at least resolve my problem.